# PhpStorm: Replace string literal with class constant

Tags: php, intellij-idea, refactoring, phpstorm, automated-refactoring

I've been trying to find out how to replace a string of an FQCN with an import statement (and vice-versa). I can't work out if this feature doesn't exist or if I just can't find it.

For example, the `ALT + ENTER` context menu in PHPUnit when creating a mock:

[image: context menu on a string literal]

PhpStorm knows which class this is - or is this a plugin doing this?

[image: class type hint on string literal]

The opposite:

[image: context menu on a class constant]

The [PHP Annotations](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7320-php-annotations) plugin adds a nice option in the context menu - but only for Doctrine:

[image: doctrine use class constant context menu]

Is there a keyboard shortcut to achieve the same result as above but with any class string literal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Php Inspections (EA Extended) plugin** has an inspection and quick fix for that: `::class can be used`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Love it! Lots of useful quick fixes and inspections! :D